# how to automatically remove blank lines - kdevelop

Tags: c, unix, ubuntu-12.04, kdevelop, kdevelop4

Is there a way/tool to automatically remove blank lines on kdevelop Version 4.3.1?

For instance, this:

```
tmpTime.tm_year = RTC_Time->bYear1 + RTC_Time->bYear;

tmpTime.tm_mon = RTC_Time->bMonth;

tmpTime.tm_mday = RTC_Time->bDay;
```

would become this:

```
tmpTime.tm_year = RTC_Time->bYear1 + RTC_Time->bYear;
tmpTime.tm_mon = RTC_Time->bMonth;
tmpTime.tm_mday = RTC_Time->bDay;
```

I do not intend with regular expression but doing it with the help of the editor.

Comment: See if this has something for you:  http://userbase.kde.org/KDevelop4/Manual/Customizing_KDevelop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding my comment above, here is a better picture highlighting why I think the referenced page will help:

[image]